# Is that possible store circular reference objects in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, scale, circular-reference

I want to scale my incoming request cross all servers.

I can done in cluster with declare global variable store all incoming request in array.

```
  //SERVER 1
    var store =[];
    //Instance node master
    http.createServer(function(req,res){


    store['InRequest1']=req;


    });
    //Instance node child
   http.createServer(function(req,res){


       var request = store['InRequest1'];
      request.write('sss');


    });
```

But if i create another instance on another server, i was unable get back the store request :

```
//SERVER 2
var request = store['InRequest1'];
request.write('sss');
```

I found the way to use memcached/redis to store the circular objects (request) but when i try to

```
 memcached.set(req); //hit error unable convert circular reference objects
```

Got anyway to scale the circular reference object ?

Answer (score 0):

> But if i create another instance on another server, i was unable get back the store request

Uh what? Unless you synchronize them across the servers, that cannot work. I'll put it another way: Guess the number I'm thinking right now! (hint: you obviously can't)

> I want to scale my incoming request cross all servers.

The latter half of your approach is the right way to go. Use a database to keep track of the data across all the servers. But you're going to have to check with the database before continuing everytime. This will lead to some problems, eventually, due to latency.

> Got anyway to scale the circular reference object ?

I don't understand this part. Can you elaborate? What circular reference?

Comment: Sorry for the store request example is not clear. Actually i want it be a session storage. With Redis store i can scale my application rite? But redis only can store objects,string... can i store the object which is circular reference in memory ? Example,
 
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis');

var Client = Redis.createClient(); 
  

RedisStore.Store(Client);

Comment: The variable Client is circular object in memory.Like reference objects.

Comment: redis ... is a database, like I said. Session in the database is a common strategy. Those are not divergent from what I said. I don't understand why you are storing the client linked to the request. The two don't correlate strongly. So putting the Client in Redis is not valid why?

Comment: Actually i dun want every new request create new Redis.createClient().I want find somewhere else to store my redis connection, and i can reuse it in future.So I can save the connections.

Comment: So you want a sort of global redis connection? So declare a globally scoped variable and reuse it. What's the problem there?